# Find the error in a direct sum of $R$-modules

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra

In what follows there is an error. The problem is that I can't find it.
Let $$0\longrightarrow L\overset{f}{\longrightarrow} M\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}N\longrightarrow 0$$ be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules and $R$-module homomorphisms. Then we have

$$M\cong\operatorname{Ker}g\oplus M/\operatorname{Ker}g$$
$$=\operatorname{Im}f\oplus M/\operatorname{Ker} g$$
$$\cong L\oplus g(M)$$
$$=L\oplus N$$

Comment: Does that sequence split?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma). By the way, are you talking about *vector spaces* over a *field* $R$ as in the title (in which case the conclusion is correct) or are you talking about $R$-*modules* over a *ring* $R$ as the question itself suggests?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry, the title is wrong, I am going to edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first line doesn't necessarily hold. Consider the short exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (abelian groups)

$$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

where the maps are the obvious ones.
The issue is that not every submodule of $M$ necessarily has a complement.

Answer (score 2):

Direct sums, really? Think of $R$ as the integers, $M$ a cyclic group of order $4$, and $L, N$ cyclic of order $2$.